# Undefined Reference in C++ with linux

Tags: c++

I have to compile a project in C++ which use a one library developed in C++. to do this I have to 1) configure : `./configure --with-spot=/usr/local`

`/usr/local` is the path where we find all `.h` and library of spot

And when I type `make` I get this error:

```
/usr/local//include/spot/tgbaalgos/reachiter.hh:102: undefined reference to     
`spot::tgba_reachable_iterator::~tgba_reachable_iterator()'
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: In which file is the spot tgba thing ?

Answer (score 0):

1. I suspect the path to the library's .h should be /usr/local/include/ but that might not be the problem.
2. When you compile, you have to include the library you want to link with too (can't see if you did that. But the undefined reference error point to the fact that the library is not found at link time.
   Something like

   gcc -lspotlibrary -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include yourcode.cpp -o yourexecutable